# An open source alternative to ConnectTunnel

Tags: vpn

I am wondering if someone can shed some light on the ConnectTunnel client from SonicWall
https://www.sonicwall.com/products/remote-access/vpn-clients/

which my university is forcing me to use to access work vpn (and seems to be a popular VPN service for many universities like https://www.dundee.ac.uk/guides/vpn-linux). It is a very closed client and I have no idea what the internals are.

What is the VPN protocol being used? Can I instead use the standard VPN protocols in Ubuntu to connect to such a VPN or perhaps another open-source VPN clients?

EDIT: I found out that the protocol is IPSec and an alternative VPN client is strongswan. Configuring strongswan with xoauth is non-trivial though and I haven't been able to figure it out.

Comment: I have given you the link to on topic for this site. You will see giving opinions is off topic. https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic

Comment: @David this doesn't seem to be asking for any opinion. It is asking a pretty concrete question: "What VPN protocol does ConnectTunnel use, and are there open source alternatives installable on Ubuntu that I can use instead of this tool?".

Comment: @David. Indeed, I am asking about protocol in ConnectTunnel (I understand this is not Ubuntu related, so is this off-topic?) and open-source alternatives.